# How to send otp in to 2 mobile nos.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send otp in to two mobile numbers. Is it possible to send?

My otp like '12345678';

for first mobile number: first 4 digit (1234)
second mobile number : last 4 digit (5678)

Need suggestion.

```
$requestParams = array(
    'user' => 'codexworld',
    'apiKey' => '****************',
    'senderID' => $senderID,
    'recipient_no' => $recipient_no,
    'message' => $message
);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to split `12345678` into two parts of equal length, or what exactly?

Comment: use `substr` to get first 4 and then next 4

Comment: one otp send to one mobile numbers. but how to send two mobile numbers.

Comment: @anbesivam, use foreach loop and each send individual

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr()` string method to split OTP. Then you can store both OTPs in two diffrent variables.

Call your SMS sending method twice. First, pass the first mobile number and first 4 digits OTP and then second-time second mobile number and last 4 digits.

You can also send them by pushing (the complete array object of each) into an array first and then using `for` loop, call SMS sending API.